# Cant get PHP WideImage class to resize a simple image

Tags: php, image, resize

So, I am just trying to resize an image with WideImage, the code is very simple and I cant get it to work. I have checked the server so GD is enabled and the PHP version is 5.2, according to the documentation at WideImage website, it should works fine.

This is my form:

```
   <form name="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php" />
        <p><input type="file" size="32" name="myimg" value="" /></p>
               <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="upload" /></p>
    </form>
```

And this is the file that receives the image:

```
<?php
require ('WideImage.inc.php');
$resize = WideImage::load('myimg');
$image = $resize->resize(400, 300);
$image->saveToFile('/imagens/1.jpg');
?>
```

I get no error simply the page becomes blank and I check the folder, the image isn't there either.
Looking at the server log, this is what I get:

```
[Sat Feb 04 16:43:35 2012] [error] [client 189.46.135.165] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/storage/8/82/8a/buenavistaviagens/public_html/Exception.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /home/storage/8/82/8a/buenavistaviagens/public_html/WideImage.inc.php on line 20, referer: http://www.buenavistaviagens.com.br/imagem.php
```

I've tried putting the class file into different folders, and now I just put it on the root and also set the permissions to 777, so, I really cant figure out whats wrong.

Any idea? thanx guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre missing `Exception.class.php` which is required by `WideImage`. You need to adjust your include path or the autoloader you are using so you can load all the classes you need.